# Where does Cron checks the time zone on Debian?

Tags: cron, timezone

I have seen number of topics that are related to my question, but non of them answers it.

Where does Cron look-up the time zone ?

```
root@awesome:~# date
Fri Feb 17 14:02:02 EET 2012

root@awesome:~# hwclock -r
Fri 17 Feb 2012 14:03:39 EET  -0.815689 seconds
```

But the Cron still works on GMT zone. (I have to make every cron job +2h to make it run properly on time)

Is there mistakes in time-zone configuration ? Or there are more time-zone configuration on Debian Linux, and I am configurationg in on the wrong one ? (I have configured my time zone via `tzselect`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to restart the cron daemon for the time zone change to take effect.

Ref: http://wiki.debian.org/TimeZoneChanges

Direct quote from the above link...

> ## Restarting Daemons and Long-Running Programs
>
> After the zoneinfo files are updated, you may need to restart daemons
> and other long-running programs to get them to use the new zone
> information. Examples of such programs include apache, bind, cron,
> fetchmail -d, inetd, mailman, sendmail, and sysklogd. A common symptom
> of this problem is seeing incorrect timestamps mixed in with the
> correct timestamps in your log files (e.g. /var/log/syslog). Even
> interactive programs like "mutt" may continue to use the old timezone
> information until they are restarted.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `tzselect` doesn't actually change your timezone, but instead gathers information for you to help you change your timezone yourself, which is mostly useful for setting up a particular user to have a timezone that differs from the system timezone.  The recommended way to change your timezone system wide is to run `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`.

Answer (score -1):

```
#dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Type the configuration command above and choose your timezone, please refer the steps below:

[image: Step one]

and

[image: Step two]

Save the settings.